# How do I set a variable to the value of an array at that given moment and not whatever the array will be?

Tags: javascript

Title is confusing but let me write this JavaScript code out:

```
var array = [0,0];
var x = array;
array[0] = 1;
alert(x);
```

The alert message then shows [1,0]. I wanted x = [0,0], I didn't want it to change when the values in the array changed. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4):

You can make a copy of the array in the state it's in with `slice`

```
var array = [0,0];
var x = array.slice();
array[0] = 1;
alert(x);
```

Of course now you no longer have a reference to the same array, but a new array, which is what you wanted.